# Save/restore the state of PHP's rand()

Tags: php, random

In an attempt to prevent memory corruption in a long-running pre-rendering script, I want to be able to say to my program "okay, render the first 1,000 steps". Then I can take a look at the output, inspect it, etc. Then I want to say "now generate steps 1,001 through 10,000".

I have it working almost perfectly. There's just one thing I'm struggling with.

The rendering script uses `rand()` to add entropy to the generated output, with `srand()` at the start to ensure it remains constant in re-renders. Currently I "solve" this issue by counting how many times `rand()` is called, and then calling it that many times before starting the actual generation. The problem with this is that it can be very slow, especially when I've generated a few million random numbers.

Is there any way to determine what value I need to pass to `srand()` to continue generating the sequence? Is this even possible?

If not, is there any way to find out what exact algorithm `rand()` is using? I really like the map I'm getting from `srand(43)` and would like to keep it if possible!

---

EDIT: Using Patashu's answer, here's what I've come up with:

```
function rnd() {
    static $seed = 42;
    $seed = $seed*214013+2531011;
    $mod = pow(2,32);
    while($seed > $mod) $seed -= $mod;
    $rs = floor($seed/65536)&0x7fff;
    return floor(2*$rs/0x8000);
}
```

It relies on the use of floats because as far as I can tell the 51 bits of the mantissa are easily enough to store the numbers with perfect precision, and integers get truncated or wrap around if bit operators are used.

Comment: The actual implementation of `rand` depends on the underlying OS. This fact can have [surprisingly effects](http://cod.ifies.com/2008/05/php-rand01-on-windows-openssl-rand-on.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page here http://cod.ifies.com/2008/05/php-rand01-on-windows-openssl-rand-on.html explains the source code for PHP's rand()

Be warned, it's not very pretty and it's dependent on quirks of PHP and your OS implementation of rand() :)

Comment: Very useful link, since it appears I can reproduce the actual RNG being used here. Edited my question to show the code I'm using, does it look right to you?

Comment: Link seems dead.

Answer (score 2):

This does not *directly* answer your question, but since it looks like you don't need particularly "good" random numbers, why not look into writing your own pseudo-random-number generator? This way you can easily serialize and deserialize its state whenever you need.

Something like the algorithm at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods may even do the trick. You can seed it with the current time whenever you start a new sequence.

Comment: This is probably my best bet. I'll lose the map I'm fond of, but I'm sure I'll find another. There's only 4 billion seeds to choose from, after all :p

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I can use something like this? `function rnd() {static $seed = 42; $seed = (($seed*0x43fd43fd+0xc39ec3)>>4)&0xffffff; return $seed%2;}` to get a random boolean value?

Comment: @Kolink Sure, looks good to me. It's probably not *very* "random" but it shouldn't be worse than what PHP does and should certainly suit your needs. You could also try it and see what kind of distribution you are getting. If you want something better you could try implementing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister